# SQL query: Separate column where IDs are the same but type is different

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I get this from a simple select query:

```
SELECT  Site.RefID, SiteName, Dates.Date, Dates.Type
FROM Site, Dates
WHERE Site.RefID = Dates.RefID; 

RefID | SiteName | Date        | Type
1       Sydney       06-12-15   OPENED
1       Sydney       08-12-15   CLOSED
2       Mel          17-12-15   OPENED
2       Mel          19-12-15   CLOSED
```

But I want to seperate it so tge result is similar to this:

```
RefID | SiteName | DateOPENED     | DateCLOSED
1       Sydney       06-12-15     | 08-12-15
```

Basically I want to compare the data tracking details

Apologies in advance if this question isn't structured very well :/ I'm a complete beginner

I was thinking maybe a select within a select or possible case when's, but I can't seem to get either working

Comment: Yeah, max(case) will get you there - but if you're using Wordpress then you're also using PHP, so you might as well do the pivot there, with a simple loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach, using `case` expression:

```
select s.RefID
     , s.Name
     , min(case when d.Type == 'OPENED' then d.Date end) as DateOPENED
     , min(case when d.Type == 'CLOSED' then d.Date end) as DateCLOSED
from Site s 
join Dates d on s.RefID = d.RefID
group by s.RefID, s.Name
```

Comment: That's case expression, not case statement.

Comment: Is case expression different to case statement, or have I just used the wrong jargon?

Comment: @JasmineB. A case expression returns a value. A case statement is a stored procedure construction used for conditional execution of code, and has no return value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY` to your current query, use `MIN` for opening date, and `MAX` for en closing date.

```
SELECT  Site.RefID, SiteName, MIN(Dates.Date) as DateOPENED, MIN(Dates.Date) as DateCLOSED
FROM Site
  JOIN Dates ON Site.RefID = Dates.RefID
group by fID, SiteName
```

Alternatively, JOIN once for opening and once for closing:

```
SELECT  Site.RefID, SiteName, do.Date as DateOPENED, dc.Date as DateCLOSED
FROM Site
  LEFT JOIN (select Refid, Date from Dates where Type = 'OPENED') do ON Site.RefID = do.RefID
  LEFT JOIN (select Refid, Date from Dates where Type = 'CLOSED') dc ON Site.RefID = dc.RefID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *conditional aggregation* to get expected result:

```
SELECT  Site.RefID, SiteName, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN Dates.Type = 'OPENED' THEN Dates.Date END) DateOPENED,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Dates.Type = 'CLOSED' THEN Dates.Date END) DateCLOSED
FROM Site
INNER JOIN Dates ON Site.RefID = Dates.RefID
GROUP BY Site.RefID, SiteName
```

Also, it is always preferable to use *explicit* instead of *implicit* join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.RefId, A.SiteName, A.Date DateOpened, B.Date DateClosed
FROM #tbl A JOIN #tbl B
ON A.RefId = B.RefID
AND A.Type = 'OPENED'
AND B.Type = 'CLOSED'
```

For the sake of simplicity, have replaced the query with `#tbl`(you can deal with it howsoever you'd like to).